# Azure Pipeline Publish ASP.Net Core App with C++ dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-c++, azure-devops

I am currently having some difficulties publishing my ASP.Net Core App within the Azure Pipeline. Due to the situation, I have to execute native C code in the APS.Net Core app. In order to have all the source code in one place, I use a C++ Dynamic Link Library as a project. I copy the resulting DLL into the build directory in the PostBuildEvent of the ASP.Net app.

This change destroys my build & publishing process in the pipeline, as we used the DotNetCore CLI there. After switching to MSBuild for the build process, it is running again. However, I can't solve the publishing error. Can anyone give me a tip on how to correct this?

Current configuration:

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish .NET Core API'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    zipAfterPublish: false
    arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
```

Comment: 1. Whether you can publish your app without any issue on your local machine using dotnet CLI? 2. Please add a variable named `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. Then run your pipeline again and share the error message in the debug log.

Comment: What is the publishing error? You didn't show that at all.